# cannot authenticate via LDAP as user has multiple UIDs

Tags: authentication, ldap, dovecot

Upgrading from SLES11 to SLES 12 I had to replace a working Cyrus mail server with dovecot.  Unfortunately I'm unable to authenticate via LDAP (which was not a problem with Cyrus):

My LDAP user has two `uid` attributes. When authenticating via IMAP dovecot detects that (`Warning: ldap(*uid*,*IP*,<*SID*>): Multiple values found for '*uid*', using '*uid2*'`).

While this shouldn't be a problem, authentication fails with no further message.  How can I authenticate without changing my LDAP user? (In UNIX/PAM I can login using either uid)

This is my `/etc/dovecot/dovecot-ldap.conf.ext` (most comments removed for brevity, and actual domain changed (not reachable anyway)):

```
# This file is commonly accessed via passdb {} or userdb {} section in
# conf.d/auth-ldap.conf.ext
hosts = ds2.domain.org ds1.domain.org
tls = yes
tls_require_cert = demand
debug_level = 0
auth_bind_userdn = uid=%u,ou=people,dc=domain,dc=org
ldap_version = 3
base = ou=people,dc=domain,dc=org
scope = onelevel

# User attributes are given in LDAP-name=dovecot-internal-name list. The
# internal names are:
#   uid - System UID
#   gid - System GID
#   home - Home directory
#   mail - Mail location
user_attrs = homeDirectory=home,uidNumber=uid,gidNumber=gid

# Filter for user lookup. Some variables can be used (see
# http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Variables for full list):
#   %u - username
#   %n - user part in user@domain, same as %u if there's no domain
#   %d - domain part in user@domain, empty if user there's no domain
user_filter = (&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=%n))
pass_attrs = uid=%n,userPassword=password
pass_filter = (&(objectClass=posixAccount)(uid=%u))
iterate_attrs = uid=user
iterate_filter = (objectClass=posixAccount)
default_pass_scheme = SSHA
```

So what's needed IMHO is a way to make dovecot continue with the user name that was used to query the userdb and passdb.
Instead it continues with the one returned from LDAP.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have multiple *uid* attribute values?

IMO you should not do that.

E.g. in the *dovecot* config some path names are derived from the username. Thus dovecot cannot reliably determine the username to be used from the LDAP search result.

Because attribute type description for *uid* does not enforce `SINGLE-VALUE` one should constrain the attribute to one value if the LDAP server permits. E.g. with OpenLDAP you set in slapd.conf (see [slapo-constraint](https://www.openldap.org/software/man.cgi?query=slapo-constraint)):

```
constraint_attribute uid count 1
```

If you already have multiple *uid* values you should sanitize your data because you will definitely run into trouble with other LDAP-enabled software too.

Comment: Simply because the schema for `uid` does not require `SINGLE`. On the user name: I pass `uid1` and `pass` for user and password, and LDAP returns a record with this `uid1` and another `uid2` *and* a matching password (challenge). Why isn't dovecot just happy, but instead complains on `uid2`? Meaning: dovecut should simply use the UID (username) I provide, nothing else.

Comment: Think about mailbox path names.

Comment: Actually I think CyrusIMAP was much more flexible than dovecot is: I had one user to access multiple mailboxes in CyrusIMAP, but dovecot seems to make that much harder, but that's a different topic...

Comment: I think I shouldn't adjust LDAP to the applications being used, but the other way round, especially when it worked so nicely with Cyrus IMAP. See my edit.